# Buildout, psycopg2, postgresql

Tags: python, django, buildout

I'm trying to make buildout config that installs psycopg2 egg and postgres from source **if needed**:

```
parts =
    ...
    postgre
    psycopg2
    ...

[postgre]
recipe = hexagonit.recipe.cmmi
url = ftp://ftp3.ua.postgresql.org/pub/mirrors/postgresql/source/v9.0.0/postgresql-9.0.0.tar.gz
configure-options =
    --without-readline

[psycopg2]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg:custom
egg = psycopg2
include-dirs =
    ${postgre:location}/include
library-dirs =
    ${postgre:location}/lib
rpath =
    ${postgre:location}/lib
```

The problem is that it always builds postgresql from source, even if the user already has postgresql installed.

How can I tell buildout to check if user already have all necessary to build psycopg2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* do it, but you'll have to make your own recipe to do that check.  There's no existing recipe that does what you want.

An alternative is to have two buildout configs.  The main `buildout.cfg` assumes postgresql is available and doesn't attempt to build it.

A second `withpostgres.cfg` could look like this:

```
[buildout]
parts +=
    postgre
    psycopg2

[postgres]
... your existing one ...

[psycopg2]
... your existing one ...
```

Users that need to build it from source can use the second configuration by calling `bin/buildout -c withpostres.cfg`.

Would that solve your issue?