# How to install readline via buildout

Tags: python, version, buildout

I would like to configure my python project to automatically build postgresql in installation process.
You can do it similar to what's described here:

[Buildout, psycopg2, postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999081/buildout-psycopg2-postgresql)

The problem is I don't like using

```
configure-options =
--without-readline
```

option

That means I have to install readline library. I looked at plone configuration files in I found some hints, so I added these parts to my buildout.cfg:

```
[readline-patch]
recipe = z3c.recipe.runscript
url = http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline/readline-5.2-patches
install-script = ${buildout:directory}/bin/fetch-readline-patches.py:fetch
update-script = ${readline-patch:install-script}

[readline]
recipe = zc.recipe.cmmi
url = http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline/readline-5.2.tar.gz
patch = ${readline-patch:prefix}/readline.patch
extra_options =
    --prefix = ${buildout:parts-directory}/opt
```

But now, I'm getting this error:

```
Installing readline-patch.
While:
  Installing readline-patch.

An internal error occurred due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mnowotka/Dokumenty/MgrFuncAdnot/app/django-gui/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-  py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1805, in main
getattr(buildout, command)(args)
  File "/home/mnowotka/Dokumenty/MgrFuncAdnot/app/django-gui/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 584, in install
    installed_files = self[part]._call(recipe.install)
  File "/home/mnowotka/Dokumenty/MgrFuncAdnot/app/django-gui/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1297, in _call
    return f()
  File "/home/mnowotka/Dokumenty/MgrFuncAdnot/app/django-gui/eggs/z3c.recipe.runscript-0.1.3-py2.7.egg/z3c/recipe/runscript/__init__.py", line 39, in install
    self.callScript(script)
  File "/home/mnowotka/Dokumenty/MgrFuncAdnot/app/django-gui/eggs/z3c.recipe.runscript-0.1.3-py2.7.egg/z3c/recipe/runscript/__init__.py", line 28, in callScript
    module = imp.load_source('script', filename)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any help with making it working would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The z3c.recipe.runscript does not have an url option. So the script will not be downloaded. You can use a local script, which will download the file and execute it. Or use http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.recipe.scriptgen to make a script by buildout which will download the file via ie curl